# According to Catholicism, who can be referred to as the One Flock of Jesus in today's context?

Tags: catholicism, gospel-of-john, gospels, judaism

In John 10:16 we see Jesus saying:

> "I  have other sheep that do not belong to this fold. I must bring them also, and they will listen to my voice. So there will be one flock, one shepherd."

Of course, Jesus meant the chosen people of Israel while referring to His one flock, and the gentiles (many of whom would later become His followers),  while referring to the 'other sheep'.

My question is: in the present context, who can be referred to as the One Flock of Jesus: the Christians or the Jews?  What do the teachings of Catholic Church tell us about it?

Comment: Each denomination will make that claim in the modern world! Besides that the  Catholic Church has always maintained it possesses the fullness of the truth, so by  consequence it is the true flock of Jesus Christ. The Jews will always remain the "chosen people" of God.

Comment: @KenGraham Paul makes a pretty convincing argument that not all jews are the chosen people, and later that being God's chosen doesn't have anything to do with race, color, or creed, but rather Jesus.

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan you are asking who the one flock is, but you only want to know what Catholics think?  The question is not really valid and i don't believe this site would allow an open ended question even though it can be answered.

Answer (score 0):

Ephesians  chapter 2 speaks of the breaking down of the barrier between Jew and gentle and the creating of one new man, where both have access to God. Ephesians 2: 14 -18. Today there are more and more Jewish people who acknowledge that Yeshua (Jesus) is the Messiah (Christ), and more and more Christians who acknowledge the Jewish roots of The Christian faith. This breaking down of the barrier between the two is creating one new humanity, one flock, and of course, one Shepherd, Yeshua (Jesus). John 10:16.

Comment: Based on what I read in all parts of the Bible, the answer is in the middle of your response.   "(those) who acknowledge that Yeshua (Jesus) is the Messiah "  Every denomination focuses on different things, but there is just one thing that unites us all.  We are His flock if we follow him...  kind of self evident.

Comment: Is this the view of Catholicism, as requested in the question?  It's important for our Q&A format that the viewpoints of questions and answers line up.

Answer (score 0):

Pope Eugene IV's encyclical [*Cantate Domino*](http://catholicism.org/cantate-domino.html) identifies "flock" with the Catholic Church and clearly excludes "Jews and heretics and schismatics" from membership in the "flock":

> The sacrosanct Roman Church…firmly believes, professes, and proclaims that those not living within the Catholic Church, not only pagans, but also **Jews** and heretics and schismatics **cannot become participants in eternal life**, but will depart "into everlasting fire which was prepared for the devil and his angels" [Matt. 25:41], **unless before the end of life the same have been added to the flock**; and that the unity of the ecclesiastical body is so strong that only to those remaining in it are the sacraments of the Church of benefit for salvation, and do fastings, almsgiving, and other functions of piety and exercises of Christian service produce eternal reward, and that no one, whatever almsgiving he has practiced, even if he has shed blood for the name of Christ, can be saved, unless he has remained in the bosom and unity of the Catholic Church.

One is "added to the flock" (i.e., made a member of the Catholic Church) by professing the Catholic Faith and being baptized, as Pope Pius XII wrote in *[Mystici Corporis Christi](https://w2.vatican.va/content/pius-xii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-xii_enc_29061943_mystici-corporis-christi.html)* §22:

> Actually only those are to be included as members of the Church who have been baptized and profess the true faith, and who have not been so unfortunate as to separate themselves from the unity of the Body, or been excluded by legitimate authority for grave faults committed. "For in one spirit" says the Apostle, "were we all baptized into one Body, whether Jews or Gentiles, whether bond or free."[I *Cor.*, XII, 13.] …

Thus, Jews (and anyone else, too) must be baptized and profess the Catholic Faith to be saved.

<sup>(cf. John 8:19, where Jesus says to the Pharisees, the precursors of modern-day Talmudic Jews: “You know neither me nor my Father. If you knew me, you would know my Father also.”)</sup>

See

- pp. 31-41 of famous 20th century Catholic theologian Msgr. Fenton's
  [*The Catholic Church and
  Salvation*](https://isidore.co/calibre#book_id=5299&panel=book_details).